# I write to a file but the changes doesn't save

Tags: c, file, csv, writetofile

I'm writing a function to change a value in a csv file, and the vs debugger says it's working perfectly, but after the program exits, I see in the file that no changes have been made. Do you know why?

```
int changeValue(int line, int row, char* text, char* fi_le)
/*line and row are the places in which the value is in the file and fi_le is
an address to the file*/
{
    int i = 1;
    char letter = ' ';
    FILE* file = fopen(fi_le, "r+");
    if (!(file))//checks that the file exists
    {
        printf("file r+ open in changeValue -- ERROR!");
        return 1;
    }
    while (i < line)//first line is number 1
    {
        letter = fgetc(file);
        if (letter == '\n')
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < row)//first row is number 0
    {
        letter = fgetc(file);
        if (letter == ',')
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(text) - 1; i++)//writes the new value in the old's value place
    {
        fputc(text[i], file);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not checking the return value from `fputc()` or `fclose()`.

Comment: fclose() must work if the file was able to open and I only need to check with fgetc() if I am in the next line and In wich row it the csv table

Comment: *fclose() must work if the file was able to open*  That's not true at all.  Per the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), **7.21.5.1  The
`fclose`
function**:  *A successful call to the
`fclose`
function causes the stream pointed to by
`stream`
to be
flushed  and  the  associated  file  to  be  closed.  Any unwritten  buffered  data  for  the  stream
are  delivered  to  the  host  environment  to  be  written  to  the  file;  any unread  buffered  data
are discarded.  Whether or not the call succeeds...*  Flushing the buffer can fail.

Comment: the function: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`,  (and cannot reliability check for EOF with a `char`.   So this line: `char letter = ' ';` should be: `int letter = ' ';`   Always compile with all the warnings enabled, then fix those warnings.

Comment: the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` (unsigned long) so the variable `i` should be declared as `size_t` not as `int`

Comment: the parameter `line` should be a `size_t`, not an `int`

Comment: the parameter `row` should be a `size_t` not an `int`

Comment: when a system function, for instance `fopen()` returns an error indication, the OS has set the variable `errno` to indicate the cause of the error.  The posted code should use: `perror( "fopen failed" );` to display on `stderr` why the OS thinks the call failed.

Comment: when everything else is corrected in the code, this line: `for (i = 0; i < strlen(text) - 1; i++)` will not output the last character in the `text[]` array.  (remember, strlen returns the index to the NUL byte, and since an offset starts at 0, the use of `text[strlen(text)]` will return the last byte of the `text` array, not the trailing NUL byte.

Comment: Note: when accessing a .csv file, (typically referencing some spread sheet layout) the layout is columns within rows, not rows within lines.  when coding, variable names should indicate usage or content (or better, both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the file is open using the `+` mode, and writes following reads, must be preceded by a call to a file positioning function.

After you read some characters from the file, you need to call either: fseek,
fsetpos, or rewind, functions.

To fix the code, store the total character count you read in from this file, and then call function fseek, where the second argument is the count and the third is SEEK_SET.

Comment: but doesn't fgetc() moves the "seek" to the next character?

Comment: @GuyShilman That isn't relevant, if you open in `+` you need to do that.

Comment: charCount = ftell(file);
fseek(file, charCount, SEEK_SET);

Comment: I added this and now it works perfectly! thanks @2501